# Sphinx: Use placeholders in roles

Tags: python-sphinx

I am working on a sphinx documentation and i am facing following problem at the moment:

I am using roles for different display options. Now i wanted to add font-awesome logos to a certain text within the role, but the placeholders i use don´t work in the role definition. Here an example:

```
:ver:`|Cubes| random text`
```

`ver` is my class and `|Cubes|` is the placeholder for the font-awesome logo.
The problem is, that the placeholder requires a white-space before and after the | but for the role definition there can´t be a white-space right after or before the `.

Is there a way to solve this without creating a different role for every logo i use in my documentation?

Thanks for every Answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  From [Interpreted Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#interpreted-text):

> Interpreted text is text that is meant to be related, indexed, linked, summarized, or otherwise processed, but the text itself is typically left alone.

See [Inline markup recognition rules](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup-recognition-rules) for details.

As an aside, what you call "placeholders" are substitions in reST terminology.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)