# Sphinx: ref in custom role

Tags: css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to have multiple links in one line, each with different css.

So I  tried to define role and use it to style some part of the line:

```
.. role:: myrole

some text, :myrole:` abc :ref:`mylink`, more text`, another text
```

But it does not work (it works if I remove the :ref: and keep there only the text).

What is the problem? How can I achieve behavior as I want?

Comment: You cannot nest an interpretation within another. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740889/sphinx-use-placeholders-in-roles/43745523#43745523

Comment: @StevePiercy Thanks. Is there any other solution how to put two css classes in one line?

Comment: From your example markup and question, it's not clear which objects you want to have hyperlinks. Sphinx renders internal objects and external URLs with different markup to which you can apply CSS. You might also try something from the docutils documentation on [Custom Interpreted Text Roles](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles). There's also the [`:raw:` role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw).