# rst link to glossary term with subscript

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, glossary

I have a sphinx glossary term like this with a replace to use subscripts for proper formatting.

```
|VOH|
   Minimum output voltage representative of a logic 1

.. |VOH| replace:: V\ :sub:`OH`\
```

How can I properly reference this term from elsewhere in my docoument also with the proper subscript formatting?  The seemingly obvious attempt below doesn't work with the replace inside the backticks.

```
:term:`|VOH|`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is close to another, but the [answer is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740889/sphinx-use-placeholders-in-roles/43745523#43745523). You cannot do this in reST alone.

Instead you could drop the replacement, define the term `VOH` alone, then do post-processing to format the text appropriately.